# Safari not "giving Permission to Open This Page" when trying to load pdf from wordpress site

Tags: permissions

I have a wordpress site, which I just moved from one domain to another, which caused some issues, which are mostly if not all fixed.

I cannot tell you if the problem has existed before, since the pdfs are a new feature on my site.

Whenever I click the link for the pdfs on my site, safaris is giving me back the following error. "You Don't Have Permission to Open This Page". Weirdly all the other browsers are just doing fine, it is just safari giving this problem.

The URL of the page is: https://www.pts-europe.com/bi-directional-dc-sources/
The Link is: Kewell EVD Series - Datasheet
The Link-URL is: "https:// bit.ly/2Mava4O"

Comment: How are the links to the PDFs added to bit.ly? It redirects to an ftp:// link, which won't work in a browser. You need to use https://.

Comment: Dang, what a obvious one. Sometimes you don't see it right away. Thank you :)